# Pass lines of text file as argument to script input?

Tags: bash

I am trying to use a java script/software that is run by doing:

```
java -jar picard.jar MergeSamFiles \
      I=input_1.bam \
      I=input_2.bam \
      O=output_merged_files.bam
```

where `I=` represents the input into the program. I have a text file with inputs that I would like to feed into this program, such as:

```
arg1
arg2
arg3
...
```

where each line gets converted into `I=arg1 I=arg2 I=arg3 ...`. Is there an easy way to do this in bash?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use an array:

```
# read file.txt to array
mapfile -t array < file.txt

# prefix every array element with "I="
java -jar picard.jar MergeSamFiles \
      "${array[@]/#/I=}" \
      O=output_merged_files.bam
```

Answer (score 1):

In plain `bash`:

```
java -jar picard.jar MergeSamFiles \
    $(IFS=$'\n'; printf "I=%s " $(<inputfile)) \
    O=output_merged_files.bam
```

or alternatively

```
java -jar picard.jar MergeSamFiles \
    $(while read -r; do echo "I=$REPLY"; done < inputfile) \
    O=output_merged_files.bam
```

or using `sed`:

```
java -jar picard.jar MergeSamFiles \
    $(sed 's/^/I=/' inputfile) \
    O=output_merged_files.bam
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this might work:

```
java -jar picard.jar MergeSamFiles $(sed -E 's/^/I=/' make_it_so.txt | xargs) O=output_merged_files.bam
```

If your input file has more args in it than xargs can flatten, you might run into some problems with the above.